# Cannot join entities with no error

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, symfony-2.8

Trying to set a relation between two entities.

Investigating with phpmyadmin showed no link between their tables.

```
/*
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Otherentity")
 */
private $otherentity;
```

instead of:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Otherentity")
 */
private $otherentity;
```

Even checking the [coding standards](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/contributing/code/standards.html) did not helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found: typo in the comment structure itself.

After searching in dozens of loosely related topics and tutos, I had to copy-paste existing relations and replace-in-place word after word... to find that the `/**` is mandatory as it is.

And easily mistaken for `/*`. And no warning anywhere.

Hope that helps anyone (at least myself, when it will happen again in several years).